# react-select doesn't show default value from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-select

**Description**

I am developing form feature. the concept is one form can perform two actions : edit and create.

**Problem**

Now, I am facing the problem. In edit mode form, default Value doesn't showing. I tried different way to solve the problem.
First code, I am using separate label object inside array and store it to variable and then mapping inside attribute value in Select component :

```
 const [dataAdmisi, setDataAdmisi] = useState({
    diagnosa: "",
    kelas: null,
    namaRuangan: null,
    noKamar: null,
    noTempatTidur: null,
    dokter: null
  });


  useEffect(() => {
    if(defaultValues) {
      setDataAdmisi((prevData) => ({
        ...prevData,
        diagnosa: defaultValues?.diagnosa,
        kelas: defaultValues?.kelas,
        namaRuangan: defaultValues?.namaRuangan,
        noKamar: defaultValues?.noKamar,
        noTempatTidur: defaultValues?.noTempatTidur,
        dokter: defaultValues?.noStr,
      }));

      setDefaultRuangan(defaultValues?.namaRuangan);
    } 
  }, [defaultValues]);

  const diagnosa = dataAdmisi?.diagnosa;
  const kelas = dataAdmisi?.kelas;
  const ruangan = dataAdmisi?.namaRuangan;
  const kamar = dataAdmisi?.noKamar;
  const tempatTidur = dataAdmisi?.noTempatTidur;
  const dokter = dataAdmisi?.dokter

  const optKelas = [
    { label: kelas }
  ];

  const optKamar = [
    { label: kamar }
  ];

  const optTempatTidur = [
    { label: tempatTidur }
  ];

  const optDokter = [
    { label: dokter }
  ];
...
  <Form.Group className="w-50">
          <FormLabel>No. Tempat Tidur</FormLabel>
          <Controller
            name="noTempatTidur"
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: true }}
            render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (
              <Select
                value={  { label: optTempatTidur.map((x) => x.label)}} 
                options={resAllTempatTidur?.map((data) => ({
                  value: Number(data?.masterTempatTidur.idTempatTidur),
                  label: `${data?.idTrTempatTidur}`,
                }))}
                onChange={(selectedOption) =>
                  onChange(selectedOption?.label)
                }
                isSearchable
                placeholder="Pilih no. tempat tidur"
                components={{
                  DropdownIndicator: () => null,
                  IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
                }}
              />
            )}
        />
          {formErrors?.noTempatTidur && (
            <span className="text-danger">Nomor Tempat Tidur harus diisi</span>
          )}
        </Form.Group>
```

Benefit using first code is that value can be visible into react select component but the minus is whenever react select have value, it always raises errors when submit.

Second code is different, I am using many attribute/props in react select.

```
 <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <FormLabel>Kelas</FormLabel>
        <Controller
          name="jenisKelas"
          control={control}
          rules={{ required: true }}
          render={({ field:{ onChange, value } }) => (
            <Select
              value={resAllListOfKelas?.getListKelas?.rows.find(x => x.idKelas === value)} 
              onChange={(selectedOption) =>
               onChange(selectedOption?.kelas)
              }
              options={resAllListOfKelas?.getListKelas?.rows ?? []}
              getOptionValue={(option) => option.idKelas}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.kelas }
              isSearchable
              placeholder="Pilih kelas"
              components={{
                DropdownIndicator: () => null,
                IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
              }}
            />
          )}
        />
        {formErrors?.jenisKelas && (
          <span className="text-danger">Pilihan Kelas harus diisi</span>
        )}
      </Form.Group>
```

Benefit using the second code is working fine, lists shown, value also shown but when we click. the minus is, default value or value doesn't show.

**Question**

I've tried all things and approach but the result always same. So, My question is what the best way for holding default value, and can change its value and also no problem with validation ?

Any help will be appreciated, thankyou.

**Full Code**
registrationAdmisi.js (as a parent)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useQuery, useLazyQuery, useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router";
import {
  GET_SINGLE_PASIEN,
  GET_ADMISI_BY_ID,
  GET_ALL_DOKTER,
  GET_ALL_TEMPAT_TIDUR,
  GET_LIST_KELAS,
  GET_ALL_ROOMS,
} from "../../../gql/layananPasienRanap/query";

import { Container, Form, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Select from "react-select";
import CardBasic from "../../../component/Common/Card/CardBasic";
import styled from "styled-components";
import DefaultAction from "../../../component/IGD/Tab/Action/DefaultAction";
import AdmisiRegisterModal from "../../../component/Admisi/Modal/AdmisiRegisterModal";
import { TabelInfoSinglePasienInap } from "../../../component/RawatInap/Table";
import { FormAdmisiDiagnosaPasien } from "../../../component/RawatInap/Form";
import { CREATE_ADMISI, UPDATE_ADMISI } from "../../../gql/layananPasienRanap/mutation";
import { Loading } from "../../../component/Common";

const FormLabel = styled(Form.Label)`
font-weight: bold;
margin-bottom: 6px;
`;

const RegistrasiAdmisi = () => {
  const { noIdentitas, idAdmisi } = useParams();
  const history = useHistory();
  const isEditMode = history.location.pathname.includes("/edit");

  const { data: fetchSinglePasien } = useQuery(GET_SINGLE_PASIEN, {
    variables: {
      noIdentitas: noIdentitas,
    },
  });

  const [fetchAllIdAdmisi, { data: fetchIdAdmisi }] = useLazyQuery(GET_ADMISI_BY_ID)

  const { data: allDokter } = useQuery(GET_ALL_DOKTER);
  const { data: allTempatTidur } = useQuery(GET_ALL_TEMPAT_TIDUR);
  const { data: allListOfKelas } = useQuery(GET_LIST_KELAS);
  const { data: allListOfRooms } = useQuery(GET_ALL_ROOMS);

  const [createAdmisi, { loading: loadingCreateAdmisi }] = useMutation(CREATE_ADMISI, {
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      console.table(data);
    },
    onError: (err) => {
      console.error(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
    } 
  });

  const [updateAdmisi, { loading: loadingUpdateAdmisi }] = useMutation(UPDATE_ADMISI, {
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      console.table(data);
    },
    onError: (err) => {
      console.error(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
    } 
  });
  
  const resIdAdmisi = fetchIdAdmisi?.getAdmisiById;

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      fetchAllIdAdmisi({
        variables : {
          idAdmisi: idAdmisi
        }
      });

    } catch(err) {
      console.error(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
    }
  }, [])
  
  const resData = fetchSinglePasien?.getSinglePasien;
  const resAllDokter = allDokter?.getAllDokter;
  const resAllTempatTidur = allTempatTidur?.getAllTempatTidur;
  const resAllListOfKelas = allListOfKelas?.getListKelas;
  const resAllListOfRooms = allListOfRooms?.getAllRooms;

  const dataPasienHeader = {
    noRm: "No. Rekam Medis",
    noPendaftaran: "No. Pendaftaran",
    tgl: "Tanggal & Waktu Pendaftaran",
    namaLengkap: "Nama Lengkap",
    usiaDanTglLahir: "Tanggal Lahir / Usia",
    jenisKelamin: "Jenis Kelamin",
    penanggung: "Penanggung",
    hubPenanggung: "Hubungan Penanggung dengan Pasien",
    namaPetugas: "Nama Petugas",
  };

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    control,
    reset,
    formState: { errors: formErrors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      jenisPembayaran: "umum",
    },
  });

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);  

  if(loadingCreateAdmisi) {
    return <Loading/>
  }

  const handleSave = (data) => {
    if(isEditMode) {
      // updateAdmisi({
      //   variables: {
      //     input: {
      //       diagnosa: data.diagnosaMasuk,
      //       kelas: data.jenisKelas.value,
      //       namaRuangan: data.namaRuangan.label,
      //       noRm: resData?.noRm,
      //       noKamar: data.nomorKamar.value,
      //       noStr: data.dokterMerawat.value,
      //       noTempatTidur: data.noTempatTidur.value,
      //     }
      //   }
      // })
      console.log(data);
    } else {
      // createAdmisi({
      //   variables: {
      //     input: {
      //       diagnosa: data.diagnosa,
      //       kelas: data.jenisKelas.value,
      //       namaRuangan: data.namaRuangan.label,
      //       noRm: resData?.noRm,
      //       noKamar: data.nomorKamar.value,
      //       noStr: data.dokterMerawat.value,
      //       noTempatTidur: data.noTempatTidur.value,
      //     }
      //   }
      // })
      console.log(data);
    }

    setShow(true);
  };


  const handleClose = () => {
    setShow(false);
    history.push(`/inap/admisi`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Container fluid>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSave)}>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <CardBasic title={"INFORMASI PASIEN"}>
                <TabelInfoSinglePasienInap
                  data={resData}
                  header={dataPasienHeader}
                />
                <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                  <FormLabel>Catatan</FormLabel>
                  <textarea
                    placeholder="Keterangan Pasien"
                    className="form-control"
                  ></textarea>
                </Form.Group>
              </CardBasic>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <CardBasic title={"DIAGNOSA PASIEN"}>
                  <FormAdmisiDiagnosaPasien
                    defaultValues={resIdAdmisi}
                    resAllDokter={resAllDokter}
                    resAllListOfKelas={allListOfKelas}
                    resAllListOfRooms={allListOfRooms}
                    resAllTempatTidur={resAllTempatTidur}
                    register={register}
                    formErrors={formErrors}
                    control={control}
                    reset={reset}
                />                    
                </CardBasic>
              </div>
              <div>
                <CardBasic title={"PEMBAYARAN"}>
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                    <FormLabel>Jenis Pembayaran</FormLabel>
                    <Select
                      name="jenisPembayaran"
                      options={[
                        {
                          value: "umum",
                          label: "Umum",
                        },
                        {
                          value: "asuransi",
                          label: "Asuransi",
                        },
                      ]}
                      isSearchable
                      onChange={(v) => {
                        setValue("jenisPembayaran", v.value);
                      }}
                      placeholder="Pilih Jenis Pembayaran"
                      components={{
                        DropdownIndicator: () => null,
                        IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
                      }}
                    />
                  </Form.Group>
                </CardBasic>
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col sm={12}>
              <div className="mt-3 pb-3 border-1 border-dark border-top">
                <DefaultAction loading={false} />
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </form>
      </Container>
      <AdmisiRegisterModal
        show={show}
        handleClose={handleClose}
        data={resData}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default RegistrasiAdmisi;
```

FormAdmisiPasienInap

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Form, FormLabel } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import Select from "react-select";

const FormAdmisiDiagnosaPasien = ({ 
    defaultValues,
    resAllDokter, 
    resAllListOfKelas, 
    resAllListOfRooms, 
    resAllTempatTidur, 
    register, 
    formErrors,
    control,
    reset,
  }) => {
  const [dataAdmisi, setDataAdmisi] = useState({
    diagnosa: "",
    kelas: null,
    namaRuangan: null,
    noKamar: null,
    noTempatTidur: null,
    dokter: null
  });


  useEffect(() => {
    if(defaultValues) {
      setDataAdmisi((prevData) => ({
        ...prevData,
        diagnosa: defaultValues?.diagnosa,
        kelas: defaultValues?.kelas,
        namaRuangan: defaultValues?.namaRuangan,
        noKamar: defaultValues?.noKamar,
        noTempatTidur: defaultValues?.noTempatTidur,
        dokter: defaultValues?.noStr,
      }));

      setDefaultRuangan(defaultValues?.namaRuangan);
    } 
  }, [defaultValues]);

  const diagnosa = dataAdmisi?.diagnosa;
  const kelas = dataAdmisi?.kelas;
  const ruangan = dataAdmisi?.namaRuangan;
  const kamar = dataAdmisi?.noKamar;
  const tempatTidur = dataAdmisi?.noTempatTidur;
  const dokter = dataAdmisi?.dokter

  const optKelas = [
    { label: kelas }
  ];

  const optKamar = [
    { label: kamar }
  ];

  const optTempatTidur = [
    { label: tempatTidur }
  ];

  const optDokter = [
    { label: dokter }
  ];

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setDataAdmisi((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      diagnosa: e.target.value,
    }));
  };
  
  return (
    <>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <FormLabel>Diagnosa Masuk</FormLabel>
        <textarea
            name="diagnosa"
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
            defaultValue={diagnosa}
            className="form-control"
            {...register("diagnosa", { required: true })}
          >             
          </textarea>
        {formErrors?.diagnosa && (
          <span className="text-danger">Diagnosa harus diisi</span>
        )}
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <FormLabel>Nama Ruangan</FormLabel>
        <Controller
          name="namaRuangan"
          control={control}
          rules={{ required: true }}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
            <Select
              options={ resAllListOfRooms?.getAllRooms.rows ?? [] }
              value={ resAllListOfRooms?.getAllRooms.rows.find((x) => x.kodeRuangan === value) }
              getOptionLabel={option => option?.namaRuangan}
              getOptionValue={option => option?.kodeRuangan}
              onChange={(selectedOption) => {
                  onChange(selectedOption?.kodeRuangan)
                }
              }
              isSearchable
              placeholder="Pilih nama ruangan"
              components={{
                DropdownIndicator: () => null,
                IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
              }}
            />
          )}
        />
        {formErrors?.namaRuangan && (
          <span className="text-danger">Nama Ruangan harus diisi</span>
        )}
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <FormLabel>Kelas</FormLabel>
        <Controller
          name="jenisKelas"
          control={control}
          rules={{ required: true }}
          render={({ field:{ onChange, value } }) => (
            <Select
              value={resAllListOfKelas?.getListKelas?.rows.find(x => x.idKelas === value)} 
              onChange={(selectedOption) =>
               onChange(selectedOption?.kelas)
              }
              options={resAllListOfKelas?.getListKelas?.rows ?? []}
              getOptionValue={(option) => option.idKelas}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.kelas }
              isSearchable
              placeholder="Pilih kelas"
              components={{
                DropdownIndicator: () => null,
                IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
              }}
            />
          )}
        />
        {formErrors?.jenisKelas && (
          <span className="text-danger">Pilihan Kelas harus diisi</span>
        )}
      </Form.Group>
      <div className="d-flex mb-3">
        <Form.Group className="w-50 me-3">
          <FormLabel>No. Kamar</FormLabel>
          <Controller
            name="nomorKamar"
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: true }}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <Select
                value={{ label: optKamar.map((x) => x.label)}}                 
                options={[
                  {
                    value: 1,
                    label: "I",
                  },
                  {
                    value: 2,
                    label: "II",
                  },
                  {
                    value: 3,
                    label: "III",
                  },
                ]}
                isSearchable
                placeholder="Pilih no. kamar"
                components={{
                  DropdownIndicator: () => null,
                  IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
                }}
              />
            )}
          />
          {formErrors?.nomorKamar && (
            <span className="text-danger">Nomor Kamar harus diisi</span>
          )}
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="w-50">
          <FormLabel>No. Tempat Tidur</FormLabel>
          <Controller
            name="noTempatTidur"
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: true }}
            render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (
              <Select
                value={  { label: optTempatTidur.map((x) => x.label)}} 
                options={resAllTempatTidur?.map((data) => ({
                  value: Number(data?.masterTempatTidur.idTempatTidur),
                  label: `${data?.idTrTempatTidur}`,
                }))}
                onChange={(selectedOption) =>
                  onChange(selectedOption?.label)
                }
                isSearchable
                placeholder="Pilih no. tempat tidur"
                components={{
                  DropdownIndicator: () => null,
                  IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
                }}
              />
            )}
        />
          {formErrors?.noTempatTidur && (
            <span className="text-danger">Nomor Tempat Tidur harus diisi</span>
          )}
        </Form.Group>
      </div>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <FormLabel>Dokter Merawat</FormLabel>
        <Controller
          name="dokterMerawat"
          control={control}
          rules={{ required: true }}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Select
              {...field}
              value={  { label: optDokter.map((x) => x.label)}} 
              onChange={(selectedOption) =>
                setDataAdmisi((prevValues) => ({
                  ...prevValues,
                  dokter: selectedOption?.label,
                }))
              }
              options={resAllDokter?.rows.map((data) => ({
                value: data?.noStr,
                label: `${data?.namaDokter}`,
              }))}
              isSearchable
              placeholder="Masukan Dokter Merawat"
              components={{
                DropdownIndicator: () => null,
                IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
              }}
            />
          )}
        />
        {formErrors?.dokterMerawat && (
          <span className="text-danger">Nama Dokter harus diisi</span>
        )}
      </Form.Group>
    </>
  );
};

export default FormAdmisiDiagnosaPasien;
```